# I can not create simple options with Simple _form grouped_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using simple_form to generate my options in the select field. It generates group options without any problem. But it does not generate the options that are not grouped.

```
<%= f.association :abstract_document_filters,
    :collection => Abstract::DocumentCategory.order(:label),
    :as => :grouped_select,
    :group_method => :abstract_document_filters,
    :group_label_method => :label,
    :label_method => :label,
    :include_blank => "Escolha a lista",  :class => 'form-control select chosen-select'  %>
```

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control grouped_select optional" name="business_child_international_document_list[abstract_document_filters_id]" id="business_child_international_document_list_abstract_document_filters_id">
<option value="">Escolha a lista</option>
<optgroup label="Assets">
    <option value="4">Pedras Preciosas</option>
    <option value="5">Ouro</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Monetização">
    <option value="1">Pessoa Fisica</option>
    <option value="2">Pessoa Jurídica Nacional</option>
    <option value="3">Pessoa Jurídica Interacional</option>
</optgroup>
```

I need to receive the following code:

```
<select class="form-control grouped_select optional" name="business_child_international_document_list[abstract_document_filters_id]" id="business_child_international_document_list_abstract_document_filters_id">
<option value="">Escolha a lista</option>
<optgroup label="Assets">
    <option value="4">Pedras Preciosas</option>
    <option value="5">Ouro</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Monetização">
    <option value="1">Pessoa Fisica</option>
    <option value="2">Pessoa Jurídica Nacional</option>
    <option value="3">Pessoa Jurídica Interacional</option>
</optgroup>
<option value="5">Títulos</option> <------------------------ I need this line
```

I understand that the problem occurs because of my collection. It's pointing to Abstract::DocumentCategory and I have an Abstract::DocumentFilter with no category. For this reason he does not find the items that are not in the collection. I wondered if there was any other way to do that.